# Deprecating old URLs using htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Currently I have this in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule            ^chart-(.*)\.php$ ./keyboard-chart.php?seo=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^keyboard-diagram-(.*)\.php$ ./keyboard-chart.php?seo=$1 [QSA]
```

However, I would like to deprecate line 2, so that something like this happens instead:

```
Whatever ^chart-(.*)\.php$ ./keyboard-diagram-$1.php
```

E.g. I want the `keyboard-diagram-$1.php` URL to appear in the browser address bar. But I don't know the correct syntax. How do I properly implement this behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a choice, whether to offer a permanent redirect or, a temporary one. Probably you want to make it permanent. There is a good explanation of why on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700621/htaccess-r-301-vs-r-302).

Currently, you are rewriting the URL internally but what you need to do is to have the browser load the new resource actually.

```
RewriteRule ^chart-(.*)\.php$ ./keyboard-diagram-$1.php [R=301,L]
```

I presume what you posted was already working on your server, on my server it doesn't redirect correctly without dropping the '.'

```
RewriteRule ^chart-(.*)\.php$ ./keyboard-diagram-$1.php [R=301,L]
                              ^
```

It might be worth setting `[R=302,L]` until you finish testing. If you use 301 and it is not doing what you want AND if your browser/any proxy remembers it can be a real pain to test. If there is even a slim possibility that the redirect may change in future you should stick with 302 - remember, 301 means permanent and really means it.

EDIT: I will write this in a more complete manner

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / #On some hosts this additional line is necessary and it is *possible* that it may need to be a path on some weird hosts or configurations
RewriteRule ^chart-(.*)\.php$ ./keyboard-diagram-$1.php [R=301,L]
# On the above line you may   ^ need to remove the dot indicated - didn't work correctly on my test with it in place.
```

Comment: It's not working for me. For instance, `http://isometricland.net/keyboard/chart-alien-vs-predator.php?sty=15&lay=1&svg=0` is redirected to `http://isometricland.net/home2/username/public_html/keyboard/keyboard-diagram-alien-vs-predator.php?sty=15&lay=1&svg=0` instead of  `http://isometricland.net/keyboard/keyboard-diagram-alien-vs-predator.php?sty=15&lay=1&svg=0`, resulting in a 404 Not Found error.

Comment: @posfan12 Mine was similar with the . in place, try without it.

Comment: Without the . it redirects to the root directory, which is not where the pages are located.

Comment: @posfan12 So, you can try with the dot, without the dot, with a separate line directly under `RewriteEngine on` reading `RewriteBase /` and without. That's four combinations to try?

Comment: @Willtech Do you absolutely need to use a `.htaccess`? So many people are fixating on this while if you have access to the server configuration files, you should put your directives there as you will gain on simplicity (specially for rewrite operations), security and performances.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I'll be honest, I have never tried to do it any other way. It is probably true that you could do this with other server configuration files but, what if the host has multiple websites? Using `.htaccess` is pretty much universal, not every host gives access to the other ones.

Comment: @posfan12 I will edit the additional line from my last comment into the answer, please let us know if you get it sorted.

Comment: "what if the host has multiple websites?" not a problem at all, each website is a `VirtualHost` block basically and you put relevant configuration in there. You can also use `Include` directives to separate configuration in multiple files. In fact in many standard installation you have one configuration file per website. But this is better in many ways than `.htaccess`, if the server is all yours of course.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Yes, and I like your caveat.

Comment: I ended up using `RewriteRule ^chart-(.*)\.php$ http://isometricland.net/keyboard/keyboard-diagram-$1.php [R=301,L]`. The fully formed complete URL did the trick. (I got this tip from a tutorial website.)